# Push Data In Javascript, As Int Not A String

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I am using Vue JS, and I have the following function within my methods:

```
add () {
    console.log(this.newData);

    this.newData.push({ JobBreakdown: '', Price: 0 });
}
```

The `newData` is setup like so:

```
newData: { 
    JobBreakdown: "",
    Price: 0 
},
```

However, whenever I `console.log` my `newData` its saves the `Price` as a string and not a number?

The add function gets called on a button with `@click`,

```
<v-btn class="AddButton" rasied @click="add">Add</v-btn>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPDATE

This is how I have setup the input elements

```
<div v-for="quote in newData" :key="quote.id">
  <v-flex xs12><v-textarea v-model="quote.JobBreakdown" auto-grow rows="1" label="Breakdown"></v-textarea></v-flex>
  <v-flex xs12><v-text-field v-model="quote.Price" label="Cost/Price"></v-text-field></v-flex>
</div>
```

I was thinking, playing around with a child component. However from what I have read, using an array like this is better. Plus I am very new to Vue JS and want to keep things simple.

Sorry must made a small mistake on code, the `newData` is an array,

```
newData: [{ 
    JobBreakdown: "",
    Price: 0 
}],
```

Sorry...

Comment: Is the `price` property bound to an input? For example, by using `v-model="Price"`?

Comment: @NinoFiliu updated my question with how I load the price data into my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am not sure if this is the best solution to this problem. However it does seem to work.

Before saving the data, I loop around the data and convert the strings into floats, like so

```
let QuoteArray = this.newData;

for(var i=0; i<QuoteArray.length;i++) {
   QuoteArray[i].Price = parseFloat(QuoteArray[i].Price)
}
```

If anyone sees any issues with this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseFloat)

```
this.newData.push({ JobBreakdown: '', Price: parseFloat(0) });
```

it depends if you want to use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` this will force your attribute price to be a float or an int as your need.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that, I did indeed try that, but it still pushes the data as a string